# I don't fully understand why Pythagorean theorem works with velocity vectors.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors, physics, visualization

I get why it works with displacement because that's what the theorem was originally meant for, lengths.... I find it harder to wrap my head around it when its velocity. If anyone has a good visualization or anything that will help me understand It will really help. I scoured the internet for a while but all of them were just:-  put V(y) velocity arrow perpendicular to V(x) head ,for some reason this explanation isn't working out for me.... well looking forward to the responses!

cheers!

Comment: If you move at velocity of $\space 5\space$ at an angle of about $\space 53^\circ\space$ with respect to the
$\space X$-axis, you are moving about $\space 3\space$ velocity units along $\space X\space$ and $\space 4\space$ along $\space Y.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works because a right triangle of velocity vectors is just a right triangle of displacement vectors, all divided by the same constant time increment.

Comment: I'm curious how this explanation extends to other vectors, e.g. adding electric fields or current density vectors.

Comment: Yeah, there are other interesting questions here, but that's not where the OP wanted to go for now, I suppose.

Comment: @Golden_Ratio Electric field is proportional to force on a charged particle, force is proportional to acceleration, acceleration is velocity over time.

Answer (score 2):

In Euclidean space, the Pythagorean theorem tells us for orthogonal vectors $u,v,$

$$\|u+v\|^2=\|u\|^2+\|v\|^2.$$

> I get why it works with displacement because that's what the theorem was originally meant for, lengths

Go back to what a vector in Euclidean space is: an object with direction and **length**. The vector may represent many things, e.g. displacement, velocity, acceleration, force, electric field etc. Since vectors have a notion of length, applying Pythagorean theorem makes perfect sense if the vector quantity obeys the [superposition principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle).

Comment: Further reading: [Is the superposition principle universal?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/47443/is-the-superposition-principle-universal#:~:text=The%20answer%20is%20that%20there,1%20and%20E2%20separately)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you’re on a ship moving with velocity $v_1$ (relative to the shore) and you’re walking with velocity $v_2$ (relative to the ship). In time $\Delta t$ the ship is displaced by $v_1 \Delta t$ (relative to the shore) and you are displaced by $v_2 \Delta t$ (relative to the ship). Your displacement relative to the shore is $(v_1 + v_2) \Delta t$. So your velocity relative to the shore is $v = v_1 + v_2$. If $v_1 \perp v_2$, then the Pythagorean theorem (which holds whenever we add orthogonal vectors) tells us that $\| v \|^2 = \| v_1 \|^2 + \| v_2 \|^2$.

If you’d like, you could apply the Pythagorean theorem to the displacement vectors then divide by $\Delta t^2$ to obtain the Pythagorean theorem for the velocity vectors.

Comment: I'm curious how this explanation extends to other vectors, e.g. adding electric fields or current density vectors.

Comment: I think the more basic question is always “why does this physical quantity add like a vector”. Once you accept that a given physical quantity adds like a vector, then the Pythagorean theorem holds (it holds whenever you add orthogonal vectors).

Comment: So there’s a fundamental fact, or modeling hypothesis, that the electric field $E$ at a point due to charges $q_1$ and $q_2$ is the sum of the electric field vectors $E_1$ (due to $q_1$) and $E_2$ (due to $q_2$). I believe that modeling assumption can only be verified by experiment — we just check if the model makes good predictions. But once you accept that $E = E_1 + E_2$, the Pythagorean theorem is just a math fact about vectors. Expand $\| E_1 + E_2 \|^2$ and the Pythagorean theorem falls out (if $E_1 \perp E_2$).

Comment: It makes sense; essentially this is the [superposition principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle). I'm quite curious myself about physical quantities that violate the principle.